# Bootstrap 4 collapse not working with map in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dictionary, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add collapse to a project where it will display all the available content when **Read More**  button (which is working for collapsing button) got clicked. But, it only collapsing for the first item that fetched from the database, and for every other **Read More** button click it is not working for that particular item rather it keeps opening and closing the first item. Below is my code that I am trying with. I need help with this issue. Thanks very much.

```
<div>
  <div className="container mt-3">
    <h1 className="text-justify mb-4">The Blogstar Blog</h1>
    <div>
      {data && data.length > 0 ? (
        data.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="card p-3 mt-3" key={index}>
              <div className="d-flex">
                <div className="text-justify mr-5">
                  <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="d-flex ml-auto ">
                  <p className="mt-2 mr-2">
                    <img
                      src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/18/000000/facebook-like.png"
                      alt="facebook-like-icon"
                    />{' '}
                    {item.upvotes}
                  </p>
                  <p className="mt-2 mr-2">
                    <img
                      src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/18/000000/thumbs-down.png"
                      alt="thumbs-down-icon"
                    />{' '}
                    {item.downvotes}
                  </p>
                  <p className="mt-2">
                    <img
                      src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/18/000000/comments.png"
                      alt="comments-icon"
                    />{' '}
                    {item.comments}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex">
                <p>
                  <img
                    src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/18/000000/clock.png"
                    alt="clock-icon"
                  />
                  {formatDate(item.createdAt)}{' '}
                </p>
                <p>
                  <img
                    className="ml-2"
                    src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/18/000000/writer-male.png"
                    alt="author-icon"
                  />{' '}
                  <strong>{item.author.name}</strong>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="text-justify">
                {ReactHtmlParser(item.content.substring(0, 150))}
                <button
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                  type="button"
                  data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target="#collapseExample"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-controls="collapseExample">
                  Read More
                </button>
                <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                  {ReactHtmlParser(item.content)}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <div>Nothing in database</div>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Video Reference Of How My Working Code Behaving]

Comment: Why not use https://react-bootstrap.github.io ?

Comment: Consider using https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I am 15sec earlier =P

Comment: @cyonder I wanted to try the project with Bootstrap that's why I am not using React Bootstrap.

Comment: @Salva Knyazev I wanted to try the project with Bootstrap that's why I am not using React Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `data-target` on your collapse button to this:

```
data-target={`#collapseExample${index}`}
```

and your collapse div to this:

```
<div class="collapse" id={`collapseExample${index}`}>
   // ... content
</div>
```

The problem was that your collapse `id` and button `data-target` were static. These values need to be dynamic depending on the data you're mapping through. Otherwise your button will always target the same element. This explains why every button collapses/expands the same `div`.

Comment: Thanks Very much for your help. It works as expected.